# How to fix Shellshock vulnerability on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux, bash, debian-squeeze

How do you fix the shellshock bash vulnerability on Debian Squeeze? (I originally posted just the answer but that got modded, go figure), so now I'll post the answer below...